# AutoCorrect worked without being passed in as a prop?

Tags: react-native, components, textinput, prop

Basically I have a component to behave like a `TextInput` as below

```
//Input.js

import React from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

const Input = ({ label, value, onChangeText }) => {
    const { inputStyle, containerStyle, labelStyle } = styles;

    return (
        <View style={containerStyle}>
            <Text style={labelStyle}>{ label }</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={inputStyle} 
                onChangeText={onChangeText}
                value={value}
            />
       </View>
    );
};
```

And I have another component that utilizing the Input from the `Input` component above

```
//InputForm.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Card, CardSection, Input } from './common';

class LoginForm extends Component {
    state = { text: '' };

    render() {
        return (
            <Card>
                <CardSection>
                    <Input 
                        autoCorrect={false}
                        value={this.state.text}
                        onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
                        label='Email'
                    />
                </CardSection>
                <CardSection />
                <CardSection>
                    <Button>
                        Login
                    </Button>
                </CardSection>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

As shown clearly in first `Input.js`, we only receive `label, value, onChangeText` as props, and in my `InputForm.js`, I'm passing an extra prop `autoCorrect`. What happened now is, auto suggestion did disabled.

Correct me if I'm wrong, `Input` component is a custom component which should not understand what `autoCorrect` means as I never define the behaviour in `Input.js`. So why it worked?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but it looks like auto suggestion disabled by default. Try to set autoCorrect={true} (or just "autoCorrect" without any value, cause it's boolean) and see what happens.

Comment: @DmitryBirin: On ios, autoCorrect by default is true, hence simply by setting it to false can see the effect here.

Answer (score 0):

The default value for the autoCorrect is true: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#autocorrect

You won't see any effect in your second example because you are not overriding the autoCorrect prop in the TextInput as you correctly said.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I understand that default value for `autoCorrect` is true, that's why in my InputForm.js, I purposely set `autoCorrect` to false. And what I mean is, by setting it to false, auto Correct did disabled. Why?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You set autocorrect to false and you are surprised it disabled the auto correction? That is what it is suppose to happen.

Comment: autoCorrect was set to Input component, where Input component is a custom component. That is why I included `Input.js` in first section of question. Under <TextInput> inside `Input` component, there isn't any setting handling or mapping for autoCorrect. Now do you get the question?

Comment: There is only one example stated in the question, a custom component named `Input` being used in another component `InputForm`.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. My guess is that you are returning a functional component which is actually a component class. this.props.autoCorrect should be the same. But you are right this does not actually make sense. Can you try debugging the TextInput to see what the props look like when it is created?